# pruning new grape vines

Tags: pruning, plant-care, fruits

I bought 3 grape vines last spring/summer (table grapes, canadice, concord, can't remember).  The grew but no grapes or flowers.

After reading it sounds like I should have pruned them before the winter, but I didn't.  Now that it is their first spring, how should I prune them.
Just one main vine and back to 2 or 3 buds, or because they've allready started budding should I jut let them grow this season ?

thanks,

Alison

Comment: Take a photo, so that we can help better. You can prune also when it is green, and probably it should be done in any case, for very young plants, but without a photo it is difficult to explain.  PS: you could also add also what form you want to give to your vines.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, grapes as usually sold are first year grafts. They need about three years to bear fruit.

Secondly, they will likely survive if you prune them now, but given that you will get no grapes, and that it is a risk, you better wait until they are dormant again.

Are you planning to train them or are they just sprawling all over the place?

You should decide how you want to grow them right now. For table grapes I assume some sort of trellis.

If you did some training, keep at it and, in Winter, cut back to the vines that are trained.

If you didn't, learn about training techniques and train the shoot that is straighter/better aligned to the main trunk. The first few years are very important so, if you messed up, cut back to one dormant bud and start over next year.

Know that you can and should remove new shoots that you don't need and that you can also pinch the tips of new vines with little worry.

Comment: I just made a trellis for them, and will cut relative to that in the winter.

Comment: As for your second point, this is just the second year so I guess I will not get any grapes, so should I prune them now, or wait until the winter.  Thanks

Comment: @user Wait until the winter. But like I said, You can do what's called green pruning(the non-woody parts)